# `html` property doesn't exists in context when running `Engine.Razor.RunCompile`

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, signalr, razorengine

I'm using SignalR and would render some HTML on server side. For this I'm using this code in my hub:

```
protected static string RenderPartialToString(string view, object model)
{
    string partialViewPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, view.Replace("~/", ""));
    string template = File.ReadAllText(partialViewPath);
    string html = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, view, null, model); // exception throwed here

    return html;
}
```

With parameters:

- **`view`:** the name and path to my view. Hard coded value when calling the method: `"~/Views/Partials/_programList.cshtml"`
- **`model`:** The data I got from a database request.

It gives me this a `RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException`:

> Errors while compiling a Template. Please try the following to solve the situation:
>
> - If the problem is about missing/invalid references or multiple defines either try to load
>
>   - the missing references manually (in the compiling appdomain!) or
>   - Specify your references manually by providing your own IReferenceResolver implementation. See https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ReferenceResolver.html for details. Currently all references have to be available as files!
> - If you get 'class' does not contain a definition for 'member':
>
>   - try another modelType (for example `null` to make the model dynamic). NOTE: You CANNOT use `typeof(dynamic)` to make the model dynamic!
>   - Or try to use static instead of anonymous/dynamic types.
>
> More details about the error:
>
> - error: (103, 22) The name `Html` doesn't exists in the current context.
>
> Temporary files of the compilation can be found in (please delete the folder): `C:\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\RazorEngine_sof105yt.k4e`.

This the code of my view:

```
@model PaginationList<Program> @* PaginationList<T> inherrits from List<T> *@
@using WebsitePUC.Models;
@using WebsitePUC.ViewModels;
@using WebsitePUC;

@foreach (var program in Model)
{
    <div class="resultcard row">
        <div class="col-xxs-12 col-sm-9  basicinfo">
            <a href="@program.Url">
                <h2>@program.Name</h2>
                @if (program.Description != null)
                {
                    @Html.Raw(program.Description) @* The error (103, 22) must stand here. *@
                }
            </a>
            <div class="details">
                <p>
                    @if (program.Locations.Any())
                    {
                        <strong>Locatie</strong><span>: @string.Join(", ", program.Locations)</span>
                    }

                    @if (program.Locations.Any() && program.StartDate.HasValue)
                    {
                        <br/>
                    }

                    @if (program.StartDate.HasValue)
                    {
                        <strong>Startdatum</strong><span>: @program.StartDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</span>
                    }
                </p>
                <p><a href="inschrijven.shtml" class="btn btn-puc">Schrijf me in</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="extrainfo">
            @if (program.Document != null)
            {
                <a href="@program.Document.ToString()">
                    <img src="~/uploads/img/uploads/cover.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                </a>
            }
            else
            {
                <img src="~/uploads/img/uploads/cover.jpg" class="img-fluid">
            }
            <div class="info">
                @InfoMaker(program.VideoStream, "opname", "Opname")
                @InfoMaker(program.VideoConference, "videoconf", "Videoconferentie")
                @InfoMaker(program.LiveStream, "livestream", "Livestream")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@helper InfoMaker(bool condition, string icon, string name)
{ 
    if (condition)
    {
        <span class="item"><span class="ico @icon"></span><span class="descr">@name</span></span>
    }
}
```

This is my code on my startup:

```
public override void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    base.Configuration(app); // Needed to load the stuff of the CMS.

    HubConfiguration hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
    hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
}
```

I've also tried this but gives me the same exception:

```
public override void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    base.Configuration(app);

    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver();
    HubConfiguration hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration()
    {
        EnableDetailedErrors = true,
        Resolver = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver
    };

    app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
}
```

I've also tried `typeof(ProgramList<Program>)` instead of the `null` in the first code block.

How could I solve this exception?

I've visisted the link in the message of the exception, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Isn't that `@Html.` something that is added by ASP.NET (Core) and therefore outside of the scope of RazorEngine? See also [here](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/508), [here](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/417) and [here](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/29).

Comment: @UweKeim: It could be possible.